# Range Query not working for text numeric in elasticsearch 6.1.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, text, range, textfield

I had tried to search the following case in elasticsearch 6.1.2

I had created a variable "rangeField" with type text and inserted following records.

```
rangeField : "1"
rangeField : "2"
rangeField : "3"
    .
    .
    .
rangeField : "12"
```

I had tried following test cases

case 1 :
searched for using range query from 1 to 5 it is returning records rangeField 1,11,12,2,3,4,5.

case 2 :
searched for using range query from 1 to 11 it is returning records rangeField 1,11.

case 3 :
searched for using range query from 1 to 23 it is returning records rangeField 1,11,12,2.

case 4 :
searched for using range query from 1 to 30 it is returning records rangeField 1,11,12,2,3.

I need to find the range correctly,

I had been using "rangeField" as text because to support the terms query,

elastic search 6.1.2

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: yes, I want to use terms query to search multiple values in a single field @Lupanoide

Comment: take a look here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/matching-an-integer-field/11025/2?u=geppo

Comment: I can match the field but I want to get within the range by using the range query

Answer (score 1):

If you change the datatype of your field `rangeField` from `text` to `integer` you are be able to perform both queries that you need. Indexing 1 as text will have the same behaviour of `range([a-z])` as you have experimented. But if you will change your mapping, modifying `dateField` datatype in `integer`, you will reach to improve a `term query` for exact value:

```
{
     "query" :
       { "term" : { "rangeField" : 1 } } 
}
```

or a `range query`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "rangeField" : {
                "gte" : 10,
                "lte" : 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But my requirement is to save a numeric field as text field

Comment: I was trying Terms query not Term query

Comment: why you need to save an integer as text?

Comment: for terms query that is only a different syntax to make more term query in a list , take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html